# Graphics Library for Node.JS

Tags: library, javascript, node.js, vector-graphics, pixel-graphics

I'm struggling to find a graphics library that can create an images and allows to draw and write text onto the image the same way a native C# GDI+ or similar API would work.

For cross-platform compatibility purposes, I'd like to develop a software using Electron and Node.JS. There is a publishing aspect to this app that requires printing very accurate generated drawings AND they have to be drawn in real world dimensions (inches, millimetres, etc.)

Obviously, it's not a challenge for a desktop application since GDI+ and similar have access to the operating system and display's properties to calculate dimensions in real world value, but can this even be achieved in a browser application?

Most of the graphics requirements are simple - draw lines, fill rectangles, etc. - but it is also very important to be able to draw text in the system's available fonts like a native application would be able to.

I found the HTML5 Canvas element which can do some of these things for display purposes, but as far as I can tell, there is no way to use it in a way that would allow printing the result and assuring real world dimensions?

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated! Thank you.